# Bottom border underline the text only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I would like the border bottom underline to look like so,

[image]

So basically it will only underline the text,

I noticed on my site ([Test set up here](http://test.jackdh.co.uk/)) it expands the full width like this below,

[image]

I've noticed I need to reduce the blue, the width/Height, although I have not managed to achieve this and keep the nav bar justified,

I did try and remove the nav-justified, and use text-align: center, but it would not center up.

Question: How can I keep the nav bar centered while having the border bottom only expanding to the length of the text.

Thank you.

Comment: perhaps wrapping the `a` text further inside a span and have the border apply for the span?

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from using `text-decoration: underline;`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just wrap the text inside the `<a></a>` tags with a span and apply the border to the `<span>`instead of the `<a>`. So you will get something like this:

```
<a class="menu" href="link"><span>Shop</span></a>
```

and then in the css something like this:

```
a.menu:hover span {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change this:

```
.nav > li > a {
     display: block;
}
```

to this:

```
.nav > li > a {
     display: inline-block;
}
```

This will help center your anchors after making them `inline-block`, there may be other knock on effects:

```
.navbar-nav.nav-justified > li{
   text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: then the buttons aren't **justified**.

Comment: Yeah they are not but it's a good first step I may be able to work from this. Thanks

Comment: @jackdh you apply some alignment to your text, but there may be other effects that manifest from this. Good luck!